# OpenCL Convolution slower than Matlab Convolution?

Tags: matlab, opencl, convolution

I thought that Matlab was going to be much slower when it comes to computing the convolution. When I tried it in my OpenCL code, the OpenCL program was nearly twice as slow as Matlab when the `conv` function was used.

Is this expected or the code on my OpenCL is just not optimised?

Here is the openCL code i found on SO. This is for the kernel

```
__kernel void lowpass(__global float *Array, __global float *coefficients, __global float *Output, __const int numOfCoefficients) {

    int globalId = get_global_id(0); 
    float sum=0.0f;
    int min_i= max((numOfCoefficients-1),globalId)-(numOfCoefficients-1);
    int max_i= min_i+numOfCoefficients;
    for (int i=min_i; i< max_i; i++)
    {
        sum +=Array[i]*coefficients[globalId-i];    
    }
    Output[globalId]=sum;
}
```

The matlab code is simply where h is the coefficients from the lowpass filter and y is the input

```
y2=conv(h,y);
```

All I am doing is applying a lowpass filter with around 512 taps to a input which has 80000000 samples. Matlab takes 1.6seconds with `conv` function and opencl takes 3.2.

**EDIT**
So this is being run on an AMD GPU with 10 compute cores and 1Gb of memory. There is an input array consisting of 80000000 samples that gets passed into the kernel, along with an array of coefficients that was generated in MatLab for a specific cutoff frequency of a Lowpass filter. The Output variable is where the values are written too.

The results from Matlab to opencl are the exact same, I am using a wav file so I can listen to it. Also when checking the properties of the wav files produced by Matlab and OpenCL they both carry the exact same information.

Comment: With the zero information you've provided, who knows?

Comment: Sorry you are right, I have added more info

Comment: @TimMcGrand You still have absolutely zero info for this question. Who is the OpenCL vendor? CPU or GPU? How accurate is you OpenCL code result compared to Matlab? How was the kernel invoked? This is a complex question in case you thought otherwise. Shower it with info. Otherwise the answer to your question "is this expected" is "sure, why not".

Comment: **10** compute cores?  And you're worried about performance?  Most people run OpenCL and CUDA on GPUs with over a thousand cores.  For example, an nVidia GTX 1060, which is not the top tier gaming card, let alone one of the scientific computing GPUs, has 1280 CUDA cores.

Comment: Have you run this through any of your GPU vendor's tools to highlight bottlenecks?

Comment: @BenVoigt Compute cores in the AMD sense are SMs in the NVIDIA parlance, of which the GTX 1060 also has 10. Modern AMD GPUs also have "over a thousand cores" in the NVIDIA sense.

Comment: I believe you'd need to parallelize it if you wanted to get good performance on a GPU.  GPUs have a lot of really slow cores.  Individually, they're not particularly powerful; they're useful because they can do many things at once.  You're only doing one thing at a time here.